# Robot Framework, how to get the value of odd row table from the Range

Tags: for-loop, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have a new task, I need to get the generated table first then from that table, I need to validate the odd rows of the table

So far, this is my script

```
    ${Count}  get element count  ${Accounting_Table_Row}
    
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    999999
        Exit For Loop If    ${i} == ${Count}
        ${M}  get text 
   xpath=//div/[@id'GeneratedTable']/table/tr[${count}]
        Run Keyword if    "${M}" != "0"    fail  transaction is not validated    ELSE    pass execution  
        transaction is validated
    END
```

I get all the generated table but I only need the odd row table. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the Python module operator (remaining of division). Here is an example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
cicle
    ${Count}=    Set Variable    ${55}
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${Count}
        ${Oddness}=    Set Variable If    ${i%2} != 0    "Odd"    "Even"
        Log To Console    var=\${i}=${i} is ${Oddness}
    END
```